# Valid to return different json-response depending on list or retrieve?

Tags: json, rest

I am currently designing a Rest API and is a little stuck on performance matters for 2 of the use cases in the system:

- List all campaigns (api/campaigns) - needs to return campaign data needed for listing and paging campaigns. Maybe return up to 1000 records and would take ages to retreive and return detailed data. The needed data can be returned in a single DB call.
- Retrieve campaign item (api/campaigns/id) - need to return all data about the campaign and may take up to a second to run. Multiple DB calls is needed to get all campaign data for a single campaign.

My question is: Is it valid to return different json-responses to those 2 calls (if well documented) even if it regards the same resource? I am thinking that the list response is a sub set of the retreive-response. The reason for this is to make to save DB calls and bandwitdh + parsing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's both fine and expected for /campaigns and /campaigns/{id} to return different information. I would suggest using query parameters to limit the amount of information you need to return. For instance, only return a URI to each player unless you see a ?expand=players query parameter, in which case you return detailed player information.